# How to play audio every X sound? in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I trying to do in this way, but it don't works

Javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('player').play();
x = document.one.numberO.value;
i = 0;
x2 = document.one.intervalO.value;
function out(){
    if ((document.one.numberO.value == "")||(document.one.numberO.value < 1)||(document.one.intervalO.value < 5)||(document.one.intervalO.value == ""))
    {
        alert("error");
    }
    else{
var intervalID = setInterval(start, x2*1000);
 i++;
 if (i == x)
 {
     clearInterval(intervalID);
 }
 }
}

function start(){
 document.getElementById('player').play();
}
```

And HTML:

```
<form name="one">
    Number <br />
    <input type="text" name="numberO"><br />
    <br />
    Interval <br />
    <input type="text" name="intervalO">
</form> 
<audio id="player" src="too.mp3"></audio>   
<div>   
    <button onclick="out();">Start</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">||</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume+=0.1"> +</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume-=0.1"> -</button>
</div>
```

I need to play sound every X seconds (i get the value from text field) for X2 times (get from the text field too)

Comment: do u want if some enter 10 in x field then sound should run 10 sec or after every 10 sec??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go :) Hope it will help you.

```js
function out() {
  x = document.getElementById('a').value;
 intrvl = setInterval("sound(x)", x*1000);
}
i = 0;
function sound(x) 
{
  if(x == i)
    {
      clearInterval(intrvl);
    }
  i++;
  
 document.getElementById('player').play();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="a">
  <input type="button" value="sec" id="s" onclick="out()">
  
<audio id="player" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-01a.mp3"></audio> 
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var audioPlayer = document.getElementById("player");
var audioPlayCount = parseInt(document.one.numberO.value);
var audioSeconds = parseInt(document.one.intervalO.value);

var start = function()
{
    audioPlayer.play();
};

var out = function()
{
    if(!audioPlayCount || !audioSeconds || audioSeconds < 5 )
    {
        alert("error");
        return;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < audioPlayCount; i++)
    {
        setTimeout(start, 1000 * audioSeconds);
    }
};
```

I haven't tested this code, but you get the idea.

Comment: Add `, 10` inside `parseInt`. And also your for loop does nothing with `i`. Additionally function declarations should be used instead of function expressions.